# React Native change integer value when button is kicked

Tags: react-native

I am having a problem changing an integer value, the code below is showing a list of item, and  control how many items will be shown when the button is clicked

The variable I want to change when it is clicked,

```
var showdata = 5;
```

code for the button and want to change it to 10 when clicked, also want the text change to Less, and showdata change back to 5 when it is for the second time

```
 <View style={externalStyle.more_buttom}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => showdata == 10}>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontWeight: "bold",
              fontSize: 13,
              color: "#FFF",
            }}
          >
            More{" "}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
```

code for the list of item, show data used at "topTen.slice"

```
<ScrollView
    vertical
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    style={{ paddingBottom: 0 }}
  >
    {isLoadingTopTen ? (
      <Text
        style={{
          fontWeight: "bold",
          fontSize: 13,
          color: "#FFF",
          textAlign: "center",
        }}
      >
        Loading top ten
      </Text>
    ) : (
      topTen
        .slice(0, showdata)
        .map((item, index) => (
          <InfoCard
            navigation={navigation}
            brand={item.Name}
            amount={item.esgrating}
            key={index}
          />
        ))
    )}
  </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use useState hooks for changing the value of showData.

```js
 const [showdata, setShowData] = useState(5)

//..........
 <View style={externalStyle.more_buttom}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShowdata(10)}>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontWeight: "bold",
              fontSize: 13,
              color: "#FFF",
            }}
          >
            More{" "}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
```

**Working Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/witty-cookie)**

[image]

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
  const [showdata, setShowData] = useState(5);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          setShowData(10);
        }}>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'pink', padding: 10 }}>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              fontSize: 13,
              color: '#000',
            }}>
            More {showdata}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```